# Can I trigger a re-seed without a model change?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My database initializer extends `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. This is generally how I want my app setup. However, *occasionally* I muck things up bad enough that I would like to go ahead and trigger drop and reseed, even though my model has not changed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Extend from [`DropCreateDatabaseAlways`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

It will always drop, re-create and seed the database.

> An implementation of IDatabaseInitializer that will always recreate
>   and optionally re-seed the database the first time that a context is
>   used in the app domain. To seed the database, create a derived class
>   and override the Seed method.

Comment: I would like to avoid the nuke if possible. Is there something less permanent?